# div tag to show on expand and hide on collapse usi ng xslt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of hyperlinks on a webpart and i would like to show a plus sign next to each link and when i click on it should expand and would like to show the description and when i click on the -ve sign it should collapse and description should be hidden. How can i acheive this using xslt. Plz privide me some suggestions. Let me know if something is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: How to write the javascript to expand/collaps on click is *not* an XSLT question at all. Provide the Javascript and everyone will give you the XSLT code to produce it. XSLT tag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dimitre mentioned, I'm not sure what xslt has to do with this, but here's the jquery:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .description { display: none; }
</style>

<div class="title" id="fruits">Fruits <span class="expand">+</span></div>
<div class="description" id="fruits_desc">
Fruits are nutritious.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $('.title .expand').click(function() {

    var expander = $(this);
    var selectedID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var desc_id = '#'+selectedID+'_desc';

    $(desc_id).toggle(function() {
      $(desc_id).show();
      $(expander).html('-');
    }, function() {
      $(desc_id).hide();
      $(expander).html('+');
    }); // toggle

  }); // click

</script>
```

xslt just transforms xml files I think?  There's a jquery library for that (google 'jquery xslt') and you might replace the hide() and show() functionality here with .html('') and .html([ajax place to load data from which pulls from an xml file transformed by xslt])

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Just save it as a .html file for an example.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".area").find('.symbol').click(function(){
            if($(this).html() == '-')
            {
                $(this).html('+');
            }else{
                $(this).html('-');
            };
            $(this).siblings('.description').toggle();
        });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .description
    {
        display:none;
    }
    .symbol
    {
        float:left;
        cursor:hand;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="area">
        <div class="symbol">+</div><a href='#'>here is a test link</a>
        <div class="description">Here is a test description</div>
     </div>
     <div class="area">
        <div class="symbol">+</div><a href='#'>here is a test link</a>
        <div class="description">Here is a test description</div>
     </div>
     <div class="area">
        <div class="symbol">+</div><a href='#'>here is a test link</a>
        <div class="description">Here is a test description</div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```