# How to expand and collapse div in xslt

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I created some dynamic divs with some data and now i'm trying to expand and collapse that divs but only first div is working but remaining divs are not working.What is wrong in my code.

javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<xsl:text>
function collapseandexpand(){
if(document.getElementById ('subList').style.display == 'none')
document.getElementById ('subList').style.display = 'block';
else
document.getElementById ('subList').style.display = 'none';         
}
</xsl:text>
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [div tag to show on expand and hide on collapse usi ng xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449095/div-tag-to-show-on-expand-and-hide-on-collapse-usi-ng-xslt)

Comment: @harshad pansuriya it is not working in my code

Answer (score 0):

Actually the dynamic elements not registered in DOM, if you are taking this  function `collapseandexpand()` only for static element, then it will not work, you have to create the same function when you load dynamic content.

I hope it works.
Thanks

Comment: :Please explain once again with small example.i'm first time using xsl and scripting